# As an intern, I often eat lunch alone -- is this a missed opportunity to talk with my colleagues about their roles?

Tags: professionalism, communication

My colleagues and I usually have lunch together, and we eat at a mid-range price. But because my finances are low towards the end of the month, I started to have lunches on my own every day to save money.

I am starting to feel bad because I ask myself whether eating lunches on my own is a missed opportunity to know my colleagues a little better. It's been a month since I interned at my current company.

Comment: For one person in one situation - yes. For another person in another situation - no. We have absolutely no way to tell whether you personally would be able to get any value from socialising with others during lunch.

Comment: Consider making your question a little clearer; Are you wondering whether you should eat with your colleagues, or are you wondering if there is anything else you can do to get to know them?

Comment: @Dukeling Elaborate a little more about "for one person in one situation - yes. For another.....no."  Well, say if my colleagues are managers, is it a missed opp.?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this question has a solution. Us answering/giving advice isn't going to make you have more money for lunch toward the end of the month. I personally don't think you miss much. Most of my colleagues don't like to talk about work during lunch and most of my managers eat lunch at their desks because they're so busy.

Comment: I mean, if you just sit there not saying anything, you can probably just have lunch alone instead. If you get to know and make friends with others (and ideally continue these relationships past just having lunch), or if you simply gather useful information, of course it's beneficial. Whether you gain enough from lunch to make the cost worth it would be something you need to figure out on your own (but having good contacts can pay out exponentially if you know how to use them). Rarely or never having lunch with others may be seen as you not being a good team player.

Comment: @jmcampbell Good question. I'm wondering if there is anything else I should ask to get to know them. I made a small observation - ever since I had lunches on my own, my colleagues are slightly quieter around me now? If I need to clarify something about our projects during work hours, I feel a bit of uneasiness from their side. It might just be me being paranoid though because they are preoccupied and I just distracted them at the wrong time.

Comment: @Dukeling Brilliant. I have something to think about then. Because I'm wondering, based on your experience, whether missing out on lunches with colleagues would affect the working relationship. These colleagues are in management roles. So I feel bad about if they see it as me not making use of my lunch hours knowing them, and since having lunches on my own, they seem quieter? I might be paranoid though.

Comment: Did you ever mention to them that you eat by yourself to save money? I'm sure they would understand then.

Comment: Most Cafes will allow you to bring your lunch inside if you are with a big group.

Comment: I would like to add that networking, or even socializing is incredibly important part of the internship. During my internships, part of the difficulty wasn't learning and producing work, but rather the need to balance the stress from learning and work, with people who who can sympathize and offer advice, whether personal or professional. Whether it was facing a wall for the project or administrative problem, having trusted coworkers whom you can go to for help is tremendously valuable beyond the cost of food and drink. But as Joe said, go at least once to see your options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It *is* a missed opportunity to network with peers and colleagues. You can learn a lot from such lunches, understand your coworkers and the company culture, learn what is going on with others, and also have an enjoyable meal.

That said, it's your choice to decide if the value you can gain from these lunches is worth the cost (in both time and money).

Some prefer to eat alone due to cost, diet, or preferring to do other things during your lunch time such as returning calls or taking a quick walk. Others value having lunches with co-workers for social, networking, or learning reasons. And other folks mix and match - eating alone some days, and joining the crowd other days.

If you haven't tried having lunch with your co-workers, you should go at least once. That way you can judge the value of being there with them and weigh it against your other options.

Comment: I would add to this excellent answer that it is worth your while to go at some interval no matter what.  This is a great opportunity to hear what is going on with your company as a whole too.